# How to replicate a computed hashed value in a SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

We have a column in a table that is a computed HASH:

[image]

[image]

My question is, how do I replicate that computed value so that I can join on it? For example, given this row:

[image]

I am trying this:

```
select (CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],hashbytes('MD2',concat('ABC-123','en'))));
```

Where `ABC-123` would be the value for `Phrase`. But that gives me a very different hash value:

> A549AB46-7111-6833-F5A9-C0102F63E822

I assume because it's not using the same `uniqueidentifier`?

What do I need to do so that I can replicate the original computed and stored hash value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hash the same data type.  So convert the target phrase to `nvarchar(max)` before hashing, and it should match.  EG

```
CONVERT([uniqueidentifier],hashbytes('MD2',cast(concat('ABC-123' ,'en') as nvarchar(max))))
```

Comment: Thanks! (I'm getting a syntax error in there somewhere)

Comment: Ignore that last comment. Copy-paste malfunction.